# Is 憨豆先生 (Mr. Bean) commonly used to refer to Rowan Atkinson even when he's playing other characters, or when he's not acting?

Tags: usage, names, movies

Among the characters Rowan Atkinson has portrayed on TV and in movies is Mr. Bean, [憨豆先生](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%86%A8%E8%B1%86%E5%85%88%E7%94%9F) in Chinese.  My impression is that people always call him 憨豆先生 (Mr. Bean) regardless of what role he is playing, not realizing his name is Rowan Atkinson ([罗温·艾金森](http://youdao.com/w/eng/rowan%20atkinson/)).  However, this may just be among people I socialize with.

**Question**: Is 憨豆先生 (Mr. Bean) commonly used to refer to Rowan Atkinson even when he's playing other characters, or when he's not acting?

Comment: Not Chinese related. That phenomenon can occur in any language in any country, using one's famous TV show role to refer to him. When this happen, are people referring to just that role in TV or the actor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No and yes.

No, because he is "officially" known as 罗温·艾金森. Some of my Chinese colleagues recognized this name, though they couldn't write it (same with me: I am a Ukrainian, and I don't know his name, but I can recognize it once I see it in writing).

Yes, because like in most parts of the world (particularly my home country Ukraine), he is most known by his character "Mr. Bean". Therefore most of my Chinese colleagues could not recognize his official name at all, unless I told them 憨豆先生 or showed his photo.